# how to display image from xml through php?

Tags: php, xml

i have two files note.xml and xml.php

here is my code of note.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<agents>
    <agent>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
    <agent>
    <image> img/primary-nav-logo.png</image>
    <name>Tommy Jenkin</name>
    <company>CJenkins Insurance</company>
    <street>Insurance150 S State Stree</street>
    <city>Linkend</city>
    <phone>(773) 561-4331</phone>
    </agent>
</agents>
```

and here is my code of xml.php

```
<?php
                $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") 
                or die("Error: Cannot create object");
                function processXML($node){
                    foreach($node->children() as $agent => $data){
                    if(trim($data) != ""){
                        echo $data;
                        echo "</br>";
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "<hr>";
                    }
                    processXML($data);
                    }
                }  
                processXML($xml);

?>
```

Now i want to display full data of xml  with the image so how can i display it.please help

Comment: `<img src="{$data->image}" />`?

Comment: yes but where i have to place that code and how because you can see i displaying data through just echo $data;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
         $xml = simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
            function processXML($node){
                foreach($node->children() as $agent => $data){      
                      $agent= trim($agent);   
                     if($agent!="" && $agent=='image'){
                           echo '<img src="'.$data.'" >';
                     }elseif($agent!=""){
                          echo $data;
                          echo "</br>";
                     }else{
                          echo "<hr>";
                     }    

                processXML($data);
                }
            }  
            processXML($xml);
```

Comment: Correct but because of this image is displayed but due to echo $data; the link of image is also displayed so what can i do

Comment: No this is not possible because if we are check for image first and after that for whole data then data can not be print

Comment: Hey do you know how to skip first element from xml fine if yes then my problem can be solved

Comment: yes i had tried this code but as i am saying that if we are trying to check first for image and after that whole data then how it can be possible because the image is part of data not data is a part of image

Comment: @Sanjay Rathod, I have updated my answer can you please check?