# How do i display a data from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, php

i have display data from xml file to the index.php like this

```
function processXML($node){
                    foreach($node->children() as $agent => $data){
                        $agent= trim($agent);   
                        if($agent=='image')
                        {
                            echo '<div><img src="'.$data.'" ></div>';
                            echo '<div>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                        elseif($agent=='id')
                        {
                             echo '<div class = "Left">';
                             echo '<input type = "button" name="Agent" id = "'.$data.'" class = "subs-btn" value = "Select this Agent" OnClick = Selected(this.id);>';
                             $_SESSION['Selected'] = $data; 
                             echo '</div>';
                             echo '<br/>';
                             echo '<br/>';

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo '<div class = "inline1">';
                            echo $data;
                            echo '</div>';
                            echo '<br/>';

                        }
                            processXML($data);
                        }


                    }  
                processXML($xml);
```

you guys can see here i am generating a button and onclick function is call - Selected(this.id);
So here is the code of function

```
function Selected(elem) {
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('subs-btn');
        var length = buttons.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            buttons[i].style.backgroundImage="url('images/subs-btn.png')";
            buttons[i].value="Select this Agent";
        }
        document.getElementById(elem).style.backgroundImage="url('images/subs-btn-act.png')";
        document.getElementById(elem).value="Agent Selected";
    }
```

So due to this agent is selected. Now i had one button at the end of the page

```
<input type = "submit" name="Continue" class = "btn btn-primary right" value = "Continue">
```

now i want to display data which is related to selected agent on another page. So how can i display this data with respect to selected agent?
Please Help.

Comment: Make an ajax call to a php script, and store the "selected agent" in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: how can you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You would need to something along the lines of the following. This is more just psuedo code than an actual working example, as I don't know what you want to display about an agent

**Note**: I am assuming you have jQuery included.

**JS**

```
function Selected(elem) {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('subs-btn');
    var length = buttons.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].style.backgroundImage="url('images/subs-btn.png')";
        buttons[i].value="Select this Agent";
    }
    document.getElementById(elem).style.backgroundImage="url('images/subs-btn-act.png')";
    document.getElementById(elem).value="Agent Selected";

    //Start here
    var AgentData = ""//something about the agent. their id or some other identifier

    //here you would make an ajax call to a php script
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST", 
        data: AgentData, 
        url: "someurl"
    });
}
```

**PHP**

```
$_SESSION["AgentData"] = $_POST["AgentData"];
```

Now you would be able to access that data about the selected agent anywhere as long as there is a valid session.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?

Comment: i want to display details of xml file. I mean i am displaying xml data with the help of php you can see my xml file in this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028391/how-to-display-image-from-xml-through-php. So you can understand what i actually want

Comment: By Function Selected i am changing background image of button and changing tect of button that agent Selected. So now this agent i want to display on another page